# How to replace all elements of a list containing column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a column containing a list of integers.

I want to map different values onto this list of integers and am encountering several problems.

Here is what I currently have (with a test dataset):

```
data = [["Item_1", [0, 3, 4]], ["Item_2", [22, 4, 5]], ["Item_3", [0, 4, 5]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Item_ID", "Values"])

# Convert to string
df["Values"] = [str(x) for x in df["Values"]]

# Find and Replace:
def replace_vals(x):

    replace_dict = {
        **{
            r"\b1\b": "A",
            r"\b12\b": "B",
            r"\b3\b": "C",
            r"\b4\b": "D",
            r"\b5\b": "E",
            r"\b22\b": "G",
        },
    }
    for pattern, replacer in replace_dict.items():
        if re.search(pattern, x, re.IGNORECASE):
            return replacer
    return x

df["corrected_vals"] = df["Values"].apply(replace_vals)
```

The rub is I want all of the values in the list to be replaced not just the first one encountered.

Is there a way to do this search and replace, or mapping in such a way that each element of the list is replaced?

Currently this is my input:

```
Item ID  Values
Item_1   [0,3,4]
Item_2   [22,4,5]
Item_3   [0,4,5]
```

And this is my output:

```
Item ID  Values    Corrected_vals
Item_1   [0,3,4]      C   
Item_2   [22,4,5]     D
Item_3   [0,4,5]      D
```

My *ideal* output is this:

```
Item ID  Values    Corrected_vals
Item_1   [0,3,4]      [C,D]   
Item_2   [22,4,5]     [D,E,G]
Item_3   [0,4,5]      [D,E]
```

Where each list element that has a pattern in the dictionary is replaced.

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This applies a mapping to a list of elements, only returning them if they are in `my_dict`:

```
my_dict = {0:"C", 4:"D", 5: "E"}
df["Corrected_vals"] = df.apply(lambda x: [my_dict.get(el) for el in x.Values if el in my_dict], axis=1)
```

output:

```
  Item_ID      Values Corrected_vals
0  Item_1   [0, 3, 4]         [C, D]
1  Item_2  [22, 4, 5]         [D, E]
2  Item_3   [0, 4, 5]      [C, D, E]
```

Note: if `Values` is a string, cast to a list of integers with:

```
import ast
df["Values"] = df.Values.apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub()` rather than returning the replacement.

```
    for pattern, replacer in replace_dict.items():
        x = re.sub(pattern, replacer, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1=df.explode('Values')#Explode

df1=df1[df1['Values'].astype(int)>0]#Filter out 0
df1['Values']=df1['Values'].apply(lambda x: chr(ord('a') + x)).str.upper()#Convert to alphas
pd.merge(df,df1.groupby('Item_ID')['Values'].agg(list).reset_index(), on='Item_ID')#Group into list and join
```